# Receiving notification on a UICollectionViewCell's (or UITableViewCell's) removal from its parent collection or table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Background:**

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that shows items in one of two modes, which the user can toggle between. Each mode uses a different class of `UICollectionViewCell`. Let's call these modes "list view" and "grid view".

When I switch modes, I call `.reloadData` on the `UICollectionView`, which redraws the collection view using the correct cell classes. Everything works fine here.

Now: Inside the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass for one type of cells, I want to be notified when the collection view that contains it switches modes. Visually, a cell which was on-screen vanishes; the collection view is drawn fully with the other type of cell. When switching back, the cell is re-displayed.

**Question:**

How can I be notified when a `UICollectionViewCell` is *"removed"* (i.e., no longer shown; I'm not sure what's happening under the hood yet) from its parent collection view?

**Notes:**

- `prepareForReuse` is not called on the cell when the collection view's `updateData` causes the cell to no longer be included.
- `willTransitionFromLayout:toLayout:` (an empty layout?) is not called.
- Overriding `didMoveToSuperview` is of no help; it is not called.
- Observing `.hidden` or `.alpha` on the cell does not work.
- The cell's `dealloc` is not called; it sticks around in the reuse queue.

Something in the cell must be changing that I can observe or hook into, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: `UICollectionViewDelegate` has this method, which from the documentation seems like it does what I am asking:

- collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:

---

Original answer:

I got this working as desired by having the `UICollectionViewController` manually notify *visible* cells of impending doom with this method when I'm about to toggle and call `reloadData`:

```
- (void)notifyCellsWillBeHidden {
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(willBeRemovedFromCollectionView)]) {
            [cell performSelector:@selector(willBeRemovedFromCollectionView)];
        }        
    }
}
```

These cells can then do what they need to do if they implement the above method.

Calling `prepareForReuse` may not a good idea because it will be called again before the cells are re-displayed, if this is a problem.

I'm still curious whether there is a way for a cell to receive notification that it is going to be made non-visible without an explicit call.